# How do I give multiple JavaScript objects across multiple files access to same private variable?

Tags: javascript, scope

If I want to span my JavaScript project across multiple source files, but have each file have access to the same private variable, how would one do that?

For example, if I have the following code:

```
APP = (function () {
    var _secret = {},
        app = {};
    // Application part 01:
    app.part01 = (function () { /* function that uses _secret */ }());
    // Application part 02:
    app.part02 = (function () { /* function that uses _secret */ }());
    //
    return app;
}());
```

How do I put `app.part01` and `app.part02` in seperate files, but still have access to _secret?
I don't want to pass it as an argument. That's just giving the secret away, as `app.part01()` could be replaced by any other function.

Maybe I am asking the impossible, but your suggestions might lead me in the right way.

I want to work with multiple files, but I don't know how. Copying and pasting everything inside a single function each time before testing is not something I want to do.

Comment: Does JS have private variables? That's a rhetorical question...

Comment: How do I call them then? Local variables?

Comment: If that's what you meant, sounds more feasible.

Comment: just .. pass them around when you create your objects? Or if there's too much indirection, store them in a value store that objects can access (via a require, import, global namespace, event callback, whatever)?

Comment: As you are working right now, it's not possible, to share _secret, between files, look at this: Variables that are not attached to the window, can't be shared. And you have a closure so _secret definitely is not at window.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I put app.part01 and app.part02 in seperate files, but still have access to `_secret`?

That's impossible indeed. Script files are executed in the global scope, and don't have any special privileges. All variables that they will be able to access are just as accessible to all other scripts.

> Copying and pasting everything inside a single function each time before testing is not something I want to do

What you are looking for is an automated build script. You will be able to configure it so that it bundles your files together, and wraps them in an IEFE in whose scope they will be able to share their private state. The most simple example:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "APP = (function () {
    var _secret = {},
        app = {};" > app.js
cat app.part01.js >> app.js
cat app.part02.js >> app.js
echo "    return app;
}());" >> app.js
```

Comment: I don't understand how to use this, but maybe I could write something in PHP to concat files together.

Comment: It's a simple bash script that reads in the files `app.part01.js` and `app.part02.js` and writes the output to `app.js` (or at least should do that, I didn't test; but I hope you understand what it means). Yes, you can write that build script in any language you are comfortable with, there are (node) js based tools as well and tools that just require a config file and do everything automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that you can share **_secret** is attaching it to the application object and then *application* object to the *window* object. Here is an example.

```js
// FIRST JS FILE...
var application; // will be attached to window

(function(app) {
  
  app.secret = "blah!"; // will be attached to application
  
})(application || (application = {}));



// ANOTHER JS FILE
var application;

(function(app) {
  
  app.method1 = function(){ console.log(app.secret); }; // will be attached to application;
  
})(application || (application = {}));
  
console.log(application.method1()); // will display 'blah!' on the console
```

**Working example on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/paduxomayo/edit?js,console)**

Comment: That's not exactly secret any more.

Comment: It's not a secret any more if it's hard coded on your javascript on the first instance, but, I understand your point.

Comment: Maybe I should have used to word 'hidden'. I want to keep the _secret hidden from objects outside of the application.

Answer (score 0):

One way I was able to accomplish this was to create a JS file that contained the global object.

```html
// Define a global object to contain all environment and security variables

   var envGlobalObj = {
      appDatabase:      process.env.YCAPPDATABASEURL,
      sessionDatabase:  process.env.YCSESSIONDATABASEURL,
      secretPhrase:     process.env.YCSECRETPHRASE,
      appEmailAddress:  process.env.YCAPPEMAILADDRESS,
      appEmailPassword: process.env.YCAPPEMAILPASSWORD
   }
 module.exports = envGlobalObj
```

Then in the files I wish to reference this object, I added a require statement.

```html
 var envGlobalObj = require("./envGlobalObj.js");
```

This allowed me to centralize the environment and secrect variables.