# Best way to share an instance of a module that is inside a closure

Tags: javascript, closures, iife

We have a site, that use closures for all the js files. Now we have one that is used in everywhere, every time that the site loads, something like this:

Let's called this file Main.js

```
(function() {
    var globalInstance;
    var other variable declarations.

    Some code that needs to be executed everywhere

    // Now the important thing
    globalInstance = new targetModule({params: params});

    More code that needs to be executed everywhere
})();
```

So far so good, right? Now every page have a js using the same pattern. let's say home.js

```
(function() {
    var home variable declarations.

    some home code;

})();
```

Now, this was intended to keep the global namespace as clean as posible, but we now need that instance of globalInstance variable, visible from our home.js, but it's not visible.

The solution could be, declare a globalInstances... **global** ... something like this...

```
var globalInstance;

(function() {
    var other variable declarations.

    Some code that needs to be executed everywhere

    // Now the important thing
    globalInstance = new targetModule({params: params});

    More code that needs to be executed everywhere
})();
```

But you know, it doesn't feel right. Could you suggestme an alternative.

Thanks

Comment: No. That's as far as it gets. You need a global to share references between scripts.

Comment: Does [How do I give multiple JavaScript objects across multiple files access to same private variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35529674/1048572) answer your question?

Comment: The game is to keep the global namespace **clean**, not to keep it *empty*.

Comment: You know, that link looks like what I was loooking for...

Comment: And you are totally right about clean not empty, lol... thanks!

Comment: Oh, yes of course, but the anwser give me the idea of a global namespace... actually, not the bash thing. But thank you very much, you helped me a lot