# Code separation for Node and the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm making a module that should work for Node.js and the browser. Right now I have this:

```
(function (exports) {
    // ... function declarations ...
})(typeof exports !== 'undefined' ? exports : this['thing'] = {})
```

You'll notice that this works nicely in both the Node environment and the browser environment - `exports` means two different things depending on the context, and it's the only thing we can change.

As I worked on the module, I noticed it got really messy. When I started to have five long function declarations plus comments in this one file, I found it hard to navigate. What is the best way, in this situation, to separate code between files?

I've tried using a naive solution with `cat` and Makefiles but this seemed clunky to me. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might be looking for the universal module declaration (UMD) pattern.

Comment: What exactly got messy, and what does this have to do with your module pattern? Are you considering how to split up code in submodules in both node and the browser, and found those to be incompatible? If so, please explain those strategies you would have used.

Comment: @Bergi sometimes I don't like having to scroll through a large file with 5-10 rather large declarations and I'd rather edit one file per declaration. Thanks for the UMD comment. I'll check it out.

Comment: So you want to split it up in more modules, if I understand you correctly? If there's a problem with that, please ask more specific. If you just want to put parts of the module in their own files, your naive solution of `cat`ening them together (like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35530158/1048572)) is actually quite good - that's the basics of every build system.