# Import code inside client side js; in current scope, at any location

Tags: javascript, module, scope

Lets say I have two files front.js and other.js. I need to add code from other.js inside front.js

front.js -

```
// blah
var obj= {
    a: function(){
        // more blah
    },

    b: function(){
        // more blah
    }, 

    /* 
    get 
    c: function(){ 
        // more blah 
    }, 
    here 
    */

    d: function(){
        // more blah
    }
};
// blah
```

other.js -

```
c: function(){
    // more blah
},
// this ^^ is all that there is in the file (invalid js)
```

How can I import code in `other.js` at the right location in `front.js`?

Comment: `c: 46,` is invalid javascript, so you can't name a file `other.js`. one option would be to make `other.js` a module that exports a value and then reference it in `front.js`. But it seems that you need to to assemble `js` code on the fly, but it's hard to tell what you're trying to do without additional details

Comment: c: 46, is invalid js, yup, I know that. I am looking at a project with different js files (not necessarily valid js), which will be valid js if joined together. Wanted to debug it without making a big js file or refactoring different files into proper modules!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Bergi, your hint was in the right direction!

I eventually did it this way:

Let's say front.js is

```
// blah
var obj= {
    a: function(){
        // more blah
    },

    // other.js

    c: function(){
        // more blah
    }
};
// blah
```

and other.js is -

```
b: function(){
    // more blah
},
```

Make an app.js with

```
var bigstr= "", otherstr= "";
var count= 0;

var frontstream= fs.createReadStream("path/to/front.js");

frontstream.on("data", function(chunk){
        bigstr+= chunk;
});

frontstream.on("error", function(error){
        console.log("front error");
});

frontstream.on("end", function(){
        var otherstream= fs.createReadStream("path/to/other.js");

        otherstream.on("data", function(chunk){
                otherstr+= chunk;
        });

        otherstream.on("error", function(){
                console.log("other error");
        });

        otherstream.on("end", function(){
                count+= 1;
                check();
        });
});

function check(){
        if(count===1){
                bigstr= bigstr.replace("// other.js", otherstr);

                fs.writeFile("path/to/newfront.js", bigstr, function(err){
                        if(!err){
                                console.log("done");
                        }
                });
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not what a clientside module loader (or even a module system in general, which rely on valid code structures) will do, it is what a **build script** does. It would just scan your files for `include` directives and replace them verbatim with the content of the referenced file. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35530158/1048572) for a simple example of joining files together.